# how to make some weight equal to other weight inin Keras?

Tags: python, keras

Assume W is weight matrix with size of [N,M] where N and M are even number. I want to make
w(2n-1,2m-1) = w(2n,2m) and
w(2n-1,2m) = -w(2n,2m-1)

I'm new to python and Keras so I have no idea how to deal with

Comment: What do you mean by weights, could you please elaborate your question a little bit, or give some more information?

Comment: This, and where does your index start? Do you assume that your first row, first column hast n=0, m=0 or n=1, m=1?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.